# Как вывести все элементы двумерного массива с помощью foreach?

Tags: java, массивы, foreach

Не могу понять, как вывести двумерный массив с помощью foreach на языке java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так можно

```
for(int[] row: myArray)
{
    for(int element: row)
        System.out.print(element);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вывод двумерного массива построчно:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[10][10];

Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```